# How can i add icon on items (android)?

Tags: android

I'm hoping that you can help me guys, i don't have any idea on adding icon on the menu. Advance thanks.

I need to look my menu the same with this one: http://developer.android.com/design/media/navigation_drawer_titles_icons.png

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Navigation Drawer Example</string>
<string-array name="planets_array">
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
    <item>Jupiter</item>
    <item>Saturn</item>
    <item>Uranus</item>
    <item>Neptune</item>
</string-array>
<string name="drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
<string name="action_websearch">Web search</string>
<string name="app_not_available">Sorry, there\'s no web browser available</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: What menu? The menu on the ActionBar, a custom menu that you created? Some type of navigation menu?

Comment: i used the navigation menu from this link http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

i was just import the project on the eclipse.

Comment: Kindly check this link http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html
i want my navigation include icon on the side of the navigation menu

Comment: Can you be more specific what exactly do you need? Do you want to create menu on ActionBar? Or menu with subitems with icons or do you want to add icons inside NavigationDrawer ListView?

Comment: something like this one http://developer.android.com/design/media/navigation_drawer_titles_icons.png

Comment: i just want to have a menu like this one http://developer.android.com/design/media/navigation_drawer_titles_icons.png

how do i add icons on the side of my menu

Answer (score 0):

Than you need to create ListView with custom adapter. Here you can find example how to do it.

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

Hope it will help you.

Comment: or if you want also headers like in example posted by you have a look at this http://sunil-android.blogspot.sk/2013/08/section-header-listview-in-android.html

Comment: is it impossible to insert an image on the item 
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>

Comment: Yes because file strings.xml provides text strings for your application.

Comment: Once again: you have to create layout file for your ListView item - with ImageView and TextView. Then create model object e.g. DrawerListItem. Next step is to create custom adpter. @Neil has posted nice example how to do it. Where is problem to do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

Here you need to add your own `Adapter` that accepts list items that contain string and icon.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Here where the adapter is set, add your own adapter
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        // Set the list's click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        ...
    }
}
```

your list item can look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background_white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and your adapter will look something like this, call it `list_item_layout.xml`

```
public class IndexAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<IndexItem> items;
    private Context context;

    public IndexAdapter(Context context, List<IndexItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (items != null && items.size() > 0) ? items.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return (items != null && items.size() > 0) ? items.get(i) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.index_list_item_layout, null);
        }

        ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(items.get(pos).iconID);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(items.get(pos).name);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

The IndexItem I use in the adapter looks like this

```
public class IndexItem {
    public final String name;
    public final int iconID;

    public IndexItem(String name, int iconID) {
        this.name = name;
        this.iconID = iconID;
    }
}
```

After you created all of this replace the `Adapter` in the `setAdapter` method with your adapter like so

```
List<IndexItem> yourIndexList = getIndexItems(); //getIndexItems will populate your text and icons

// Here where the adapter is set, add your own adapter
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new IndexAdapter(this, yourIndexList));
```

the `getIndexItems` method can look something like this

```
public List<IndexItem> getIndexItems() {
    List<IndexItem> returnList = new ArrayList<IndexItem>();

    Stirng [] text = {"Mercury","Venus","Earth","Mars","Jupiter","Saturn","Uranus","Neptune"};
    int [] icons = {R.drawable.mercury,R.drawable.venus,R.drawable.earth,R.drawable.mars,R.drawable.jupiter,R.drawable.saturn,R.drawable.uranus,R.drawable.neptune};

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        returnList.add(new IndexItem(text[i], icons[i]));
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

add this in your main_activity.xml :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#F3F3F4"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

add this in your Main_Activity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private ListView listView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private MyActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(this);
adapter.add(new MenuModel("Title Menu", 0, 0, true));
adapter.add(new MenuModel("Food",R.drawable.your_drawable, 43, false));
adapter.add(new MenuModel("Beverage", R.drawable.your_drawable, 17, false));
adapter.add(new MenuModel("Juice",R.drawable.your_drawable, 10, false));
adapter.add(new MenuModel("Snack",R.drawable.your_drawable, 7, false));
adapter.add(new MenuModel("Other", 0, 0, true));
adapter.add(new MenuModel("Setting",R.drawable.action_settings, 0, false));

listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(arg2 == 1){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Food.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if(arg2 == 2){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Beverage.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if(arg2 == 3){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Juice.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if(arg2 == 4){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Snack.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if(arg2 == 6){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Gallery_Menu_Paket_Active.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }
});

drawerToggle = new MyActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout);
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}

private class MyActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle{

    public MyActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity mActivity,DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout){
            super(mActivity,mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
boolean drawerOpen = drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(listView);
menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public class MenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MenuModel> {

    public MenuAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return getItem(position).isGroupTitle() ? 0 : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            return !getItem(position).isGroupTitle();
    }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

             MenuViewHolder holder = null;

             int type = getItemViewType(position);
             MenuModel menu= getItem(position);

             if (convertView == null) {

                     switch (type) {
                     case 0:

                             convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_row_group, null);
                             holder = new MenuViewHolder((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_title),null, null);
                             break;
                     case 1:
                             convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_row, null);

                             holder = new MenuViewHolder(
                                             (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menu_title),
                                             (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_icon),
                                             (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_counter));
                             break;
                     }
                     convertView.setTag(holder);
             } else {
                     holder = (MenuViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
             }


             holder.titleView.setText(menu.getTitle());
             if(type != 0){
                     holder.iconView.setImageResource(menu.getIcon());
                     if (menu.getCounter() > 0) {
                             holder.counterView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                             holder.counterView.setText(menu.getCounter() + "");
                     } else {
                             holder.counterView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     }
             }
             return convertView;
     }

     public class MenuViewHolder {
         public final TextView titleView;
         public final ImageView iconView;
         public final TextView counterView;

         public MenuViewHolder(TextView titleView, ImageView iconView,
                         TextView counterView) {
                 this.titleView = titleView;
                 this.iconView = iconView;
                 this.counterView = counterView;
         }
 }

}

public class MenuModel {

    private String title;
    private int icon;
    private int counter;
    private boolean isGroupTitle;

    public MenuModel(String title, int icon, int counter, boolean isGroupTitle) {
        this.title = title;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.counter = counter;
        this.isGroupTitle = isGroupTitle;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
}

public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
}

public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
}

public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
}

public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
}

public boolean isGroupTitle() {
        return isGroupTitle;
}

public void setGroupTitle(boolean isGroupTitle) {
        this.isGroupTitle = isGroupTitle;
}
}

}
```

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
- RestaActivityDrawer cannot be resolved to a type
- Food cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: oh that `RestaActivityDrawer.this` is for my current project. you should change to `MainActivity.this`. i already edit my answer

Comment: i have an error on this code:

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
 mTitle = title;
 getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

Error says: The method setTitle(CharSequence) of type MainActivity.MenuModel must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: i have the same error with onPostCreate and onConfigurationChanged. 

inline with that inside the onPostCreate and onConfigurationChanged it has error on super.onPostCreate and super.onConfiguratio....

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
 mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

The method onPostCreate(Bundle) is undefined for the type Object